# Sending date to php web service from Simulink using webwrite function

Tags: php, matlab

I am trying to send data to PHP web service from Simulink using webwrite Matlab function in Matlab block, but the function does not work. The data does not reach the web service. I am using it in a code which runs on raspberry pi. I am using the following code:

```
coder.extrinsic('webwrite'); 
coder.extrinsic('weboptions'); 
 url = 'http://alnnovative.com/rts.alnnovative.com/security.php'; 
 response = webwrite(url, "marium", "post");
```

Can anybody tell me that what is the problem with the code?

**Note:** I can access my web service using the same code via Matlab (excluding coder.extrinsic, as it's used in Simulink only, so there is no problem in web service.

PHP Code:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");


$complete="marium";

fwrite($myfile, $complete);

echo "Data is received";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the service, not from your code... can you access it?

Comment: Yes, I can use the same code via Matlab and access my web service, but cannot from Simulink

Comment: I think there is an issue with how the payload is json-encoded here or how you are managing to decode it PHP side... can I see how you handle the post data in your service?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo even when I send simple numeric data and not JSON and change weboptions accordingly, it does not work either.

Comment: When I run this code I get the same error from Matlab too... "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo It works for me on Matlab. Anyways, the simpler code that I edited in the question, does not work in Simulink

Comment: When post data is added... the service throws an error instead of returning a valid json response. The error contains HTML formatted data, so `webwrite` fails to convert it to valid json.

Comment: The service returns this `'<br />
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in
<b>/home3/alsonsrnd/public_html/rts.alnnovative.com/security.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
'` which can't obviously be a valid json response.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Yes, right now I have not added any valid response. I just added a simple code in PHP, whenever file is accessed, a new file is created on server. So, I am not checking response right now. When using the same code via Matlab, file is created, from Simulink, it is not

Comment: Wow, that script looks like a real mess. You are reading raw post data (`file_get_contents('php://input')`) but also accessing the `$_POST`. And then you are trying to merge them into a single variable that must be written to file? On a side note, your script is returning null on your modified example and I can't see how... since it should return `Data is received` if everything goes fine.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo  Right now I am not using the below code actually, I am just checking the file creation part, which tells me that my service is accessed. I will use and edit it later according to how I want to access data. I have commented other parts, you should get response now

Comment: Ok the problem must be searched back in your first Matlab code... you were trying to merge a json object to a string, receiving an obvious error. Now the problem is that when you use `weboptions('MediaType','application/json','ContentType','json')` and a structure payout, you are expecting a json-encoded object to be retured... and this obviously cannot happen with a string... add this at the beginning of the script `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo The problem here is that when I am deploying to hardware, webwrite is not working.  I don't need solution for weboptions and header etc.